# Swap a negative value in an R data table with the previous column value

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data table where I want to swap negative values by assigning them the positive value in the previous row for the same column. for ex:

```
1 2 3 4
2 -3 -2 3
```

should be

```
1 2 3 4
2 2 3 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a data.table, a data frame, or a matrix?

Comment: It's a data.table

Comment: Could you share `dput(head(yourtable))` so that we have a reproducible example of the first few rows? Also, what should happen if there are multiple negative values in a row?

Comment: It's a huge table. I don't mind sharing but its just a 180 columns by 5000 rows of numbers. 

The assumption that I forgot to mention is that the first value will always be positive, therefore recursively this is solved.

Comment: `dput(head(yourtable))` would include only the first six rows.

Comment: Edited the question. Realized I made a mistake (sawp between rows and not columns). will post put in a minute

Comment: have a look at `tidyr::fill`

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no answers from more experienced guys, here is what I've come up with.

```
# I'm reconstructing your example:
n <- matrix(c(1, 2, 2, -3, 3, -2, 4, 3), nrow = 2)

n
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2   -3   -2    3

changeMat <- function(mat) {
  new_mat <- mat
  for(i in 1:length(mat))
    ifelse(mat[i] < 0, new_mat[i] <- mat[i-1], new_mat[i] <- mat[i])
  return(new_mat)
}

changeMat(n)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    2    3    3
```

I checked that for `data.table` object `dt` `changeMat(as.matrix(dt))` would work properly.

Anyway, I am pretty sure that there must be smarter way...